# Sorting an array on value and not on key

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, associative-array

**I want to sort this array:**

```
 Array ( [0] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb0 [hendel] => 7.7 ) [1] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb1 [hendel] => 4.13 ) [2] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb2 [hendel] => 6.61 ) [3] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb3 [hendel] => 7.22 ) [4] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb4 [hendel] => 3.13 ) [5] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb5 [hendel] => 6.91 ) [6] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb6 [hendel] => 7.3 ) [7] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb7 [hendel] => 6.65 ) [8] => Array ( [qid] => 1_2_qb8 [hendel] => 6.7 ) [9] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb0 [hendel] => 7.43 ) [10] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb1 [hendel] => 7.7 ) [11] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb2 [hendel] => 7.39 ) [12] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb3 [hendel] => 7.83 ) [13] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb4 [hendel] => 7.26 ) [14] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb5 [hendel] => 7.04 ) [15] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb6 [hendel] => 7.65 ) [16] => Array ( [qid] => 1_3_qb7 [hendel] => 7.43 ) [17] => Array ( [qid] => 1_4_qb0 [hendel] => 7.22 ) [18] => Array ( [qid] => 1_4_qb1 [hendel] => 7.26 ) [19] => Array ( [qid] => 1_4_qb2 [hendel] => 7.43 ) [20] => Array ( [qid] => 1_4_qb3 [hendel] => 8.09 ) )
```

From high to low on "hendel" but the "qid" must be related to the "hendel" value.
sorting array's doesn't work. **(asort, arsort, ksort, krsort => flags: sort_nummeric)**

**Printing values without sorting:**

```
1_2_qb0 : 7.7
1_2_qb1 : 4.13
1_2_qb2 : 6.61
1_2_qb3 : 7.22
1_2_qb4 : 3.13
1_2_qb5 : 6.91
1_2_qb6 : 7.3
1_2_qb7 : 6.65
1_2_qb8 : 6.7
1_3_qb0 : 7.43
1_3_qb1 : 7.7
1_3_qb2 : 7.39
1_3_qb3 : 7.83
1_3_qb4 : 7.26
1_3_qb5 : 7.04
1_3_qb6 : 7.65
1_3_qb7 : 7.43
1_4_qb0 : 7.22
1_4_qb1 : 7.26
1_4_qb2 : 7.43
1_4_qb3 : 8.09
```

**with sorting (krsort):**

```
1_4_qb3 : 8.09
1_4_qb2 : 7.43
1_4_qb1 : 7.26
1_4_qb0 : 7.22
1_3_qb7 : 7.43
1_3_qb6 : 7.65
1_3_qb5 : 7.04
1_3_qb4 : 7.26
1_3_qb3 : 7.83
1_3_qb2 : 7.39
1_3_qb1 : 7.7
1_3_qb0 : 7.43
1_2_qb8 : 6.7
1_2_qb7 : 6.65
1_2_qb6 : 7.3
1_2_qb5 : 6.91
1_2_qb4 : 3.13
1_2_qb3 : 7.22
1_2_qb2 : 6.61
1_2_qb1 : 4.13
1_2_qb0 : 7.7
```

Comment: It's a mess of code, but I think old friend `usort` will do the stuff

Comment: `usort($myArray, function($a,$b) {if ($a['hendel'] == $b['hendel']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return ($a['hendel'] < $b['hendel']) ? -1 : 1; });`

Comment: @MarkBaker I think, then it's `return $a['hendel']<$b['hendel']?-1:$a['hendel']!=$b['hendel']` :p

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [`usort()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) function:

```
usort($array, function(array $a, array $b) {
    if($a['hendel'] == $b['hendel']) {
        return 0;
    }
    return $a['hendel'] < $b['hendel'];
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a comparison of array sorting functions provided by PHP here : https://www.php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php. You certainly will find what you need here.

You may use custom rules to sort your array, or use existing sorting functions.